# How to make Github app connect after approval

Tags: python, authentication, github-api, github-app

We have a GitHub app that can be installed on a repository. This works using the [GitHub app authorization flow](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#web-application-flow) that returns back an installation_id that we use to associate a user account on our web app with their GitHub repository. In this case we get a callback to our url: `/callback?setup_action=install&installation_id=<installation_id>`

This typically works fine, but there are some scenarios where the authorization flow doesn't complete in a single step. In many GitHub orgs, it requires approval from an admin before the app can be installed. In these cases we don't immediately get the installation_id in the url but a request state: `/callback?setup_action=request`, and once the admin approves we get the `installation_id`.

In this case, since the approval step is completed by a different user, we don't have our web app session to associate the user with this `installation_id`. Is there a way to identify the user / account of the original request when the authorization is approved?

Comment: No, I asked GH support team and they said that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to preserving a state?
https://docs.github.com/en/apps/maintaining-github-apps/installing-github-apps#preserving-an-application-state-during-installation

You can then save the userId/account in that state like so:

```
https://github.com/apps/<app name>/installations/new?state=<userId>
```

Once the setup is complete, the `state` parameter will be included in the callback like so:

```
https://yourapplication.com/?installation_id=<number>&setup_action=install&state=<userId>
```

Comment: Yes that only works if the installation is approved immediately. When the approval happens as a separate step by someone else, this state is not returned back in that approval step.